# why is this Effect not stuck in infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

```
useEffect(() => {
  const controller = new AbortController();

  fetchReviews();   

  setNewReviewAdded(false);

  return () => {
    controller.abort();
  };
}, [newReviewAdded]);
```

I wanted this effect to run initially and whenever new reviews are added, so in this effect after fetching the new reviews it sets newReviewAdded to false, so that on successful submission of the review i could again change newReviewAdded to true which cause this effect to run and fetch the updated reviews.

but when trying this i was expecting this useffect to get stuck in infinite loop because, I am updating the state newReviewAdded which is added as dependency array, but thankfully it did not get stuck in infinite loop. can someone please explain why the effect did not fall into infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `newReviewAdded` is initially `true`, the `useEffect` will run once when the component is mounted and a second time when the value is changed to `false`. The second time `setNewReviewAdded` will not change anything, because the value is already `false`, therefore no change is happening and the `useEffect` hook will not run.

Answer (score 0):

@peperoli told you what is wrong

> If newReviewAdded is initially true, the useEffect will run once when
> the component is mounted and a second time when the value is changed
> to false. The second time setNewReviewAdded will not change anything,
> because the value is already false, therefore no change is happening
> and the useEffect hook will not run.

How to fixed it?

1: change `newReviewAdded` to number and after each fetch incress it by one `setNewReviewAdded(c => c + 1)` this way you useEffect get triggered on each change

2: set the boolean to the opposite value on each added review `setNewReviewAdded(b => !b)`

Comment: It could also be toggled with `setNewReviewAdded(x => !x)`

Comment: @UncleDave updated the answer